# ¿Por qué los datos no se insertan en la base de datos?

Tags: php, mysql

Necesito insertar datos en 2 tablas: una almacena archivos subidos y otra almacena los datos para enviar una notificacion sobre los datos que fueron insertados en la otra tabla.

Resulta que el INSERT de la tabla de notificaciones "Teacher_notification" funciona perfectamente: al subir el archivo, manda la notificación como debería ser, pero no me esta Insertando los datos en la otra tabla que son los mas importantes.

He subido archivos "Word" con menos de 5MB de espacio. Aún así, no funciona, me aseguré de que los campos de la base de datos fueran idénticos con el del INSERT del MYSQL.

```
<?php

    include('session.php');
    require("opener_db.php");
    $errmsg_arr = array();

    $errflag = false;


    $assignment_id  = $_POST['id'];
    $name  = $_POST['name'];
    $get_id = $_POST['get_id'];
    function clean($str) {
    $str = @trim($str);
    if (get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
        $str = stripslashes($str);
    }
    return mysql_real_escape_string($str);
    }

    //Sanitize the POST values
    $filedesc = clean($_POST['desc']);
    //$subject= clean($_POST['upname']);

    if ($filedesc == '') {
    $errmsg_arr[] = ' Falta la descripcion del archivo';
    $errflag = true;

    }

    if ($_FILES['uploaded_file']['size'] >= 1048576 * 5) {
    $errmsg_arr[] = 'El archivo excede los 5mb de tamaño';
    $errflag = true;
    }


    if ($errflag) {
    $_SESSION['ERRMSG_ARR'] = $errmsg_arr;
    session_write_close();
    ?>

   <script>
   window.location = 'downloadable.php<?php echo '?id='.$get_id;  ?>';
   </script>
   <?php exit();

    }

    $rd2 = mt_rand(1000, 9999) . "_File";


    if ((!empty($_FILES["uploaded_file"])) && ($_FILES['uploaded_file']['error'] == 0)) {
    //revisar si es un archivo de imagen o si pesa mas de 350kb
    $filename = basename($_FILES['uploaded_file']['name']);

    $ext = substr($filename, strrpos($filename, '.') + 1);

    if (($ext != "exe") && ($_FILES["uploaded_file"]["type"] != "application/x-msdownload")) {
        //Donde guardare el archivo   
        //$newname = dirname(__FILE__).'/upload/'.$filename;
        $newname = "admin/uploads/" . $rd2 . "_" . $filename;
    $name_notification  = 'Subio la respuesta de una asignacion con el nombre:'." ".'<b>'.$name.'</b>'; 
        //Chequear si hay un archivo con el mismo nombre en el servidor
        if (!file_exists($newname)) {
            //Mover archivo a otro lado
            if ((move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploaded_file']['tmp_name'], $newname))) {

                 echo "It's done! The file has been saved as: ".$newname;          
                $qry2 = ("INSERT INTO student_assignment (fdesc,floc,assignment_fdatein,fname,assignment_id,student_id) VALUES ('$filedesc','$newname',NOW(),'$name','$assignment_id','$session_id')")or die(mysql_error());
                mysql_query("INSERT INTO teacher_notification (teacher_class_id,notification,date_of_notification,link,student_id,assignment_id) VALUES ('$get_id','$name_notification',NOW(),'view_submit_assignment.php','$session_id','$assignment_id')")or die(mysql_error());
               //$result = @mysql_query($qry);
                $result2 = $connector->query($qry2);
                if ($result2) {
                    $errmsg_arr[] = 'Notificacion guardada en la base de datos y el documento fue subido exitosamente';
                    $errflag = true;
                    if ($errflag) {
                        $_SESSION['ERRMSG_ARR'] = $errmsg_arr;
                        session_write_close();
                        exit();
                    }
                } else {
                    $errmsg_arr[] = 'notificacion no guardada pero el documento fue subido exitosamente';
                    $errflag = true;
                    if ($errflag) {
                        $_SESSION['ERRMSG_ARR'] = $errmsg_arr;
                        session_write_close(); ?>
                           <script>


      window.location = 'downloadable.php<?php echo '?id='.$get_id;  ?>';

   </script>
   <?php
                        exit();
                    }
                }
            } else {

                $errmsg_arr[] = 'Subida de archivo ' . $filename . ' exitosa';
                $errflag = true;
                if ($errflag) {
                    $_SESSION['ERRMSG_ARR'] = $errmsg_arr;
                    session_write_close(); ?>
       <script>
       window.location = 'downloadable.php<?php echo '?id='.$get_id;  ?>';
   </script>


   <?php
                    exit();
                }
            }
        } else {

            $errmsg_arr[] = 'Error: File >>' . $_FILES["uploaded_file"]["name"] . '<< already exists';
            $errflag = true;
            if ($errflag) {
                $_SESSION['ERRMSG_ARR'] = $errmsg_arr;
                session_write_close(); ?>
       <script>
         window.location = 'downloadable.php<?php echo '?id='.$get_id;  ?>';
   </script>
   <?php

                exit();
            }
        }
    } else {

        $errmsg_arr[] = 'Error: Los archivos no pueden pesar mas de 5mb';
        $errflag = true;
        if ($errflag) {
            $_SESSION['ERRMSG_ARR'] = $errmsg_arr;
            session_write_close(); ?>
            <script>




    window.location = 'downloadable.php<?php echo '?id='.$get_id;  ?>';
       </script>
       <?php
            exit();
        }
    }
    } else {


    $errmsg_arr[] = 'Error: El archivo no fue subido';
    $errflag = true;
    if ($errflag) {
        $_SESSION['ERRMSG_ARR'] = $errmsg_arr;
        session_write_close(); ?>
       <script>
   window.location = 'downloadable.php<?php echo '?id='.$get_id;  ?>';
   </script>
   <?php
        exit();
    }
    }


    mysql_close();
    ?>
```

Todo está bien pero no inserta. ¿Qué puede estar pasando?

Comment: ¿Que error te da cuando no inserta?

Comment: Por qué no insertas de la misma forma que en teacher_notification? Es decir así `mysql_query($qry2)`. No soy experto en php pero haces dos cosas diferentes

Comment: No me da ningun error, solo no me toma el insert. He hecho de todom incluso inserte igual que en teacher_notification y tampoco me inserta,